# Understanding weird character syntax in PS1 bash prompt

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash, ps1

Here is my bash prompt:
[image: bash]

Here is the `PS1` that generates that

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]`__git_ps1`    \$ '
```

Now, here is the stuff I understand:

- `$debian_chroot` - used for `su` & `sudo`
- `u` - user
- `h` - host
- rest chars like `\033` are for colors.

What I don't understand is what is generating space **AFTER** `rails` and **BEFORE** `(master)`? What character does that? I would like to remove that space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__git_ps1` function is generating it. Edit the file the function is defined in.

Comment: The `__git_ps1` function is [supplied by git](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L234). what is the space character there which I need to remove?

Comment: Or wrap it with your own function to trim the space. `gitps1 { local g=$(__git_ps1); echo "${g# }" }`